# Can I say something like "a such-written essay"?

Tags: adjectives

I am expressing that one writing method is not good. If we follow that method, **the essay written with that method** is likely to be of a poor quality.

Can I say "**A such-written essay** is likely to be of a poor quality."?

If not, could any one please provide a condensed and formal way of doing so?

BTW, I am writing a formal technical paper.

Comment: No. _Such_ is a free form quantifier and can't be combined.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks! Then what may I use instead? I am looking for a condensed and formal way of doing so.

Comment: Just say what you did in the first sentence of your question: an essay written using that method. Or just “such an essay”, if the context makes it clear that you are talking about this method of writing.

Comment: Have you considered if *such* or *so* is the right word? You are qualifying the verb, not the noun. In any case, the sentence structure does not suit a 'formal technical paper'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

John Lawler's comment that *such* is a free form quantifier and can't be combined may be true, but a related form, “A thusly-written essay” is a possibility.  However, while that form is grammatically correct, it's clumsy.

Perhaps adopt the phrase  “such an essay” as suggested in another comment, or consider forms like “An essay so written...” or “An essay written that way...” or “An essay in that style...”.

Comment: “An essay so written...” is just the voice in my head that I am trying to look for! Thanks!